# WSGI & Python subprocess

Tags: python, wsgi

I would like to use WSGI (Web Server Gateway Interface) instead of CGI (Common Gateway Interface) because I've been reading that it's more efficient as it doesn't spawn a new process for each request.

Here is a hello world app using WSGI:

wsgi.py

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    content = "Hello, World!"
    status = '200 OK'
    header = [('Content-type', 'text/html')]
    start_response(status, header)
    return [content.encode('utf-8')]
```

I would like to know if it's OK to separate `wsgi.py` from the application by doing a subprocess from `wsgi.py` to the application? So the WSGI hello world app will look something like this:

app.py

```
import json

response = {
    'status': '200 OK',
    'header': [('Content-type', 'text/html')],
    'content': "Hello, World!"
}
response = json.loads(response)
print(response)
```

wsgi.py

```
import sys
import subprocess
import json

def application(environ, start_response):
    # Do a subprocess to the hello world app
    script = '/path/to/my/app.py'
    arg1 = json.loads(environ)
    response = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, script, arg1])

    response = json.dumps(response)
    status = response['status']
    header = response['header']
    content = response['content']

    start_response(status, header)
    return [content.encode('utf-8')]
```

Does the subprocess from `wsgi.py` to the application defeat the purpose of using WSGI? Is this setup basically the same as using CGI where it spawns a new process for each request?

Comment: Yea4, you probably want to look into a different model - perhaps running the functions in a thread instead. Even outside of WSGI, running Python as a subprocess of Python should usually be avoided. What task does the other script perform?